# Changing the order of $\int_0^2 \int_{-\sqrt{2y-y^2}}^{{2+\sqrt{2y-y^2}}} f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$

Tags: calculus

I don't really know how to do this one. I could transform those square roots into equations of circles, so I have a guess, that it is going to be something like: 
$$\int_0^2\int_{\sqrt{1-x^2}+1}^{\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}+1} f(x,y) \mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x$$
But, I'm not really confident.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: first draw the region and then you will have the answer
$$ \int_0^1\int_{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}} f(x,y)dydx+\int_1^2\int_0^2f(x,y)dydx+\int_2^3\int_{1-\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}}^{1+\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}} f(x,y)dydx$$

Comment: I tried to, but I don't really see yet what I should do. What do you mean by this sum? I'm sorry, I'm very new to multi-variable calculus.

Comment: @MátéKadlicskó, draw the region.